# Is there an ajax `select`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Autocomplete inputs make life easier. However, I am working on a project where the customer insists on having ordinary inputs (radio buttons, checkbox groups and drop down selects). I don't want to change sever-side code and plan to write a javascript function to create these form elements on the client side. I think the best approach is to give a plain textbox input a class and transform it with the function to the ultimate input type. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I thought I'd check if this has already been done. Google didn't bring expected results, so I turn to SO, have you seen such function/plugin?

Comment: How are the title and body of your question related?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - If there is such a thing, it will be powered with ajax and could well be called 'ajax select'

Comment: @Majid Select as in SELECT elements (drop-down lists)? From what I understand, you want to serve a HTML page containing INPUT text-boxes, and then you want to use JavaScript to replace those text-boxes with other types of form elements, correct? Where does Ajax come into play?

Comment: I think you need to describe the functionality of this a little more clearly.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Correct. And to convert a textbox to a select you need a number of options, these options are fetched from the server, much like an autocomplete fetches matches from the server, but this time, the options are pulled from the server without user intervention and the function receiving them creates the select (or other input types). Ajax is used to get these.

Comment: @Majid So, you want do build a web-page on the server-side, then send it to the client, and than - on page load - send more requests to the server for additional data? If it's on page load anyway, then why not just get the job done while you are still on the server (before sending the page in the first place)?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Saving requests is not a priority in this particular project, but keeping things simple, is. I have answered this question in the comment in response to Mark Bessey

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Also, it's not `building` the form on the server, because with this approach the form could be static content and served from a file without any alteration.

Comment: @Majid So you want to serve a static page to the client, and then, on the client-side, "build" the page via JavaScript/Ajax. What data format are you considering for the additional data? JSON, XML, HTML fragments, ... ?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Are you hooked?! Do you want us to write this together? I think json is the best bet, with it you can easily return value-lable pairs. I plan on more features like, serving up to `max-num` options and adding a `get more options` as the last.

Comment: @Majid Sorry, but I'm not interested. The issue seems to be simple enough, though. If the additional data is static, too, then JSON is a good choice. You just pull that data via Ajax and generate the SELECT element based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one now ;) here is [slightly modified jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KYbg/1/) (because we don't want to pull data from a real server). The code in a real application would be something like this:

Markup

```
Please choose the product:<br/>
<!-- not all products; only what we have on stock -->
<input type="text" id="product">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getScript('available_products.php', function() {

    // we assume the server would return an array like this:
    // var products = ['33712:Product A', '12501:Product B', '14619:Product C'];

    var myoptions = '';
    $.each(
    products, function(n, p) {
        var pp = p.split(':');
        var i = pp[0];
        var v = pp[1];
        myoptions += '<option value="' + i + '">' + v + '</option>';
    });

    $('#product').replaceWith('<select id="product">' + myoptions + '</select>');

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to serve a form with a bunch of text inputs, then transform it on the client to other forms of inputs (checkboxes, etc)? Not sure I really understand the motivation for this (it'd be easier to just serve up a form that matches what the customer wants, I think), but you should be able to do that using [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) or the related functions.

It does seem like something's missing from your description here, though - you'll need to edit the server-side to put a class on each input anyway, so why not just change the type there instead?

Comment: I think I'll end up writing the function. Your understanding is correct, the motivation is keeping things simple. Suppose you have a handfull of forms where you need to get a user-id, it is easier to have a textbox for it with a `user-id` class and have a single script which queries the users table and returns user-ids and display names as json data. Without this, you will have to parse a select for each form.